# cannot boot to the newly compiled kernel version

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have a server with RHEL 7.5 OS. The inbox kernel version on the system is 4.14.0-49. I have a requirement to use the latest available kernel, so I downloaded the Kernel 4.17.18 source package and compiled it on my system. So now I have both the kernels in place.

However I cannot boot to the newly compiled kernel version 4.17.18, I see the following error message when I instruct it to boot.

```
        error: invalid magic number.
        error: you need to load the kernel first.

        Press any key to continue...
```

Here is the splash screen of the boot options available on my server. Fortunately I can still boot to the old kernel version(4.14.0-49) on my system.

```
  Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server (4.17.18) 7.5 (Maipo)
  Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server (4.14.0-49.el7a.aarch64) 7.5 (Maipo)
  Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server (0-rescue-68f1601b5f1c4eb09734921b3db38f
```

Is there a configuration step that I'm missing?

Comment: It seems you tried to load the wrong file. What are the names of your file and file file that works? What is the output of `file` for both files?

Comment: I think new kernel is not able to chroot or not able to understand filesystem, can you try to mount with live media and try to boot manually?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you try to load the wrong architecture kernel file `aarch64` where your working kernel seems to be `amd64`. Use `file` command on the kernel images, or `uname -a` on a running system, to see what architecture you need, and use the proper version then.

`aarch64` is related to ARM Processors.

Comment: My system's kernel architecture is aarch64. i download the kernel compilation source from this link - https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git.

Comment: There is a difference in the file type between the newly compiled kernel(of type data) and the previous kernel(of type gzip compressed data).

[root@localhost boot]# file * | grep vmlinuz
vmlinuz:                                                 symbolic link to `/boot/vmlinuz-4.17.18'
vmlinuz-0-rescue-68f1601b5f1c4eb09734921b3db38f87:       gzip compressed data, from Unix, max compression
vmlinuz-4.14.0-49.el7a.aarch64:                          gzip compressed data, from Unix, max compression
vmlinuz-4.17.18:                                         data

Comment: It looks like you've used the uncompressed version. It should be possible to load that with bootloaders (which might need configuration changes), but I don't recommend doing it. The uncompressed file is ways bigger than the gzipped one, and will take ways longer to load during boot.

Comment: As your target architecture is quite specific, I'd recommend to look through the location where you built the kernel, and check `arch/aarch64/linux/boot`. I expect that you can find the proper compressed file there. Typically this location contains several kernel images, often there is a bzImage which is compressed with bzip, one with zImage which should be gzipped, and the raw image often called vmlinux. It might be that you need to re-run your build command with something like `make bzImage` or `make zImage` to create these compressed files.